# Serialize/deserialize Jackson JsonIdentityInfo object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, jackson

I am currently using the Jackson Object Identity feature (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity) in order to serialize/deserialize cyclic Java objects into JSON that are then retrieved/submitted through Ajax calls.  This works perfectly for this purpose, but what I need now is to be able to deserialize these objects in JavaScript so that I can work with them in their true cyclic object form before I then serialize them again to be submitted.  I have been unable to find any resources related to how this Jackson feature could be implemented in JavaScript and am hoping to not have to write this manually as it seems like something that would probably already exist.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: this question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208167/deserialize-jackson-object-in-javascript-containing-jsonidentityinfo