# angular equals method fails because of "too much recursion"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsog

I have a javascript object graph that contains cyclical references.  When I use this object in angular, firefox gives me the following error message (the "..." contains 100+ duplicates of the same line preceding and following it):

```
Error: too much recursion equals@http://localhost:8080/ops/bower_components/angular/angular.js:995:1 
equals@http://localhost:8080/ops/bower_components/angular/angular.js:997:15 
equals@http://localhost:8080/ops/bower_components/angular/angular.js:997:15
...
equals@http://localhost:8080/ops/bower_components/angular/angular.js:997:15 
equals@http://localhost:8080/ops/bower_components/angular/angular.js:984:17 
equals@http://localhost:8080/ops/bower_components/angular/angular.js:997:15 
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8080/ops/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12491:1 
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8080/ops/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12762:13 
done@http://localhost:8080/ops/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8357:34 
completeRequest@http://localhost:8080/ops/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8571:7 
createHttpBackend/</xhr.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:8080/ops/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8514:1
```

Is there a way to tell angular to consider objects equal if they match X levels deep?  Or does angular just not work with cyclical references?

**The Backstory (in case you wanted to know)**

I was having trouble finding a solution in jackson which would not serialize objects that have already appeared on a particular traversal path.  This seems like it should be pretty straight forward to me, but I guess the functionality doesn't exist.  That's when I stumbled upon jsog in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24684251/125864) which enabled me to transfer my object graph (w/ circular dependencies) over to javascript.  I was very happy that jsog did this for me, but then I encountered the above error.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that angular does not support circular references in the equals method.  I forked it, committed a fix, and submitted a pull request.  Then I found out that similar fixes had already been considered, but rejected because of either performance issues or browser compatibility.  For my project, I don't care about browser compatibility, so I'll be using my own patched version of angular to support circular references.

pull request discussion here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/9762#issuecomment-60282505

git fork here:
https://github.com/andersonbd1/angular.js

Comment: AngularJS does support cyclic references.  Possibly this was added after you did your research.  "During a property comparison, properties of function type and **properties with names that begin with $ are ignored.**" -- from [the angular.equals doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals)

Comment: @andersonbd1 you are exactly right. In my case, I need to ng-repeat over children of a tree node. since a child contains the reference to its parent, it broke the angularJs `equals`. I think this is a common scenario to support, so I scratched my version of `equals`[https://github.com/zipper01/modifiedNgEquals/tree/master]. Then when I look again I found you already made a patched version so maybe I wasted my time. But thanks for pointed this out -- l spent a day and half to detect the issue before I read your answer here.

Comment: @jk7 even if that is the case it is not for users but for themselves. Forcing a name convention does not make any sense. It can be easily supported [https://github.com/zipper01/modifiedNgEquals/tree/master] but they let it there as a potential bug; no idea why they made it that way.

Answer (score -1):

AngularJs has a good interface for equals, I suggest taking a look: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals

```
angular.equals(o1, o2);
```

It does deep searches, however I am not sure if this can be modified
Also here is something that describes the performance of angular.equals
http://jsperf.com/angular-equals