# Unable to deserialize Json that contain 2 objects with the same ID using jackson

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization, fasterxml

I have used jackson JsonIdentityInfo to handle the recursive object reference in spring mvc.
I came across one issue i.e., Unable to deserialize Json that contain 2 objects with the same ID.

```
{

    "organizations": [
        {
            "organizationId": 1,            
            "organizationName": "org1",
            "enterprise": {
                "enterpriseId": 1,              
                "enterpriseName": "ent1",
                "organizations": null
            }
        },
        {
            "organizationId": 2,            
            "organizationName": "org2",
            "enterprise": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

if you see above, both organizations are mapped with enterprise "1". For the first organization it is whole enterprise object but for organization 2, it is giving ID only. 
I need to get the whole object for organization 2 as well.

My POJO declarations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "organizationId")
public class Organization implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "organization_id")
    private Long organizationId;

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "enterprise_organization", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "enterprise_id") })
    private Enterprise enterprise;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "enterprise")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "enterpriseId")
public class Enterprise extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "enterprise_id")
    private Long enterpriseId;
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "enterprise")
    private List<Organization> organizations;
    ...
}
```

I searched google and SO but no luck.

What are the changes needed to deserialize Json that contain 2 objects with the same ID ?

Comment: what happens if you change `private List<Organization> organizations;` to `private Set<Organization> organizations;`

Comment: @Patrick I have changed List to Set. Still same issue. FYI, I am using mapping table. So NO issue with the datatype.

Comment: @Krishna Dont think you can do that in a simple generic way. Probably can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/24684251/1032167 or implement custom id Generator, but i think it will be much harder to read and understand then custom serializer/deserializer.

Comment: @Krishna btw if you need only deserialization, you can look at https://github.com/varren/JsonIdentityInfoAlwaysAsObjectSerializationJackson had similar problem back in the days. It is more like a hack that a solution...

Comment: @varren thanks for your response. In the link you provided, it is hard coded with "id", how can I do it for different id names like "enterpriseId", "organizationId" etc.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tries, @JsonIgnoreProperties solved my problem.

example: "@JsonIgnoreProperties(allowSetters = true, value = { "enterprise" })"