# Is there any way to use JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference in both directions?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I am able to serialize from Child to Parent (JsonManagedReference -> JsonBackReference) but its not working for Parent -> child.

Is there any way to do that ?

I also tried with the JsonIdentityInfo. Here, I am unable to deserialize Json that contain 2 objects with the same ID.
I have created a question:

[Unable to deserialize JSON with same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078057/unable-to-deserialize-json-that-contain-2-objects-with-the-same-id-using-jackson)

Comment: One option is to use multiple object mappers with different mixins, but i think it will be hard to read and maintain, so probably no point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of tries, implemented the traversing bi-directional with @JsonIgnoreProperties

example: "@JsonIgnoreProperties(allowSetters = true, value = { "enterprise" })"